# Refreshing function with setTimeout

Tags: javascript

How would I refresh a function with setTimeout? I want the hi function to alert every 3 seconds is there a method for this?

```
function hi(){
  alert("hi");
}
setTimeout(hi,3000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `setInterval(hi, 3000)` or

```
function hi(){
  alert("hi");
  setTimeout(hi,3000);
}
hi()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setInterval(hi, 3000);` instead of `setTimeout(hi, 3000);`

Answer (score 0):

You can essentially do this one of two ways:

```
function hi() {
    alert('hi');
}
setInterval(hi, 3000);
```

OR

```
function hi() {
    alert('hi');
    setTimeout(hi, 3000);
}
setTimeout(hi, 3000);
```